# Downvotes and the maximum daily reputation

Tags: discussion, reputation, down-votes, up-votes, daily-reputation-limit

Due mostly to my two answers to the popular question [Are there any open mathematical puzzles?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/532544/39599), I received $35$ upvotes today (in the sense of UTC time). As a user can only receive reputation for $20$ upvotes in one day, I received $200$ reputation from this activity. A couple of minutes ago I received a downvote (annoyingly, with no comment left) for my answer to the question [Subgroups of $D_4$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/532229/39599), and there was a deduction of $2$ reputation. So in a day with $35$ upvotes and one downvote, I had earned $198$ reputation. If I had received the downvote first and then the $35$ upvotes, I would have earned $200$ reputation (I know this because since writing, I received another upvote which gave we $2$ reputation).

Should the order of the votes effect the total reputation? Is this the way the system has to be in order for a user to be penalised when a post of theirs is downvoted?

Comment: I was surprised that it works this way. This meta.SO thread seems to confirm it: [Why do the up-votes after reaching daily rep cap not contribute to compensate the subsequent down-votes?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160120/) Interestingly, as I learned from [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173381/why-dont-i-have-the-mortarboard-badge/181103#181103) (it was linked in the thread that Zev posted), this does not influence whether the day is counted towards Mortarboard, Epic, and Legendary badges.

Comment: Also, send my regards to Yaar.

Comment: One of the reasons that the order of votes matters is that he "day" refers to a 24 hour period, so it is a rolling total as opposed to a function which resets itself at midnight GMT or something.

Comment: @user1729: *What* is a rolling total?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Sorry, the reputation contributing to your daily cap. If you earn 100rep at 0900 20/10/2013 and 100rep at 2100 20/10/2013 then at 0901 21/10/2013 you will be able to earn 100rep.

Comment: Would it be overkill to permit the evisceration of non-commenting down-voters?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you mean "should" in the sense of "*the system is designed to operate that way*", then yes, the order of votes matters. This is similar to how downvotes and upvotes don't commute for new users, since a user's reputation is required to be $\geq 1$.

If you mean "should" in the sense of "*we want the system to operate that way*", then I think even the SE team's answer is no, but as was explained in [this meta.SO answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184318/161783), it would apparently be very difficult to implement, and it would have a relatively minor effect, so this will not be changed.

Answer (score 6):

Yes. the order of the votes matter. You have eight more hours to get more votes and cover these downvotes.